# Sell Apps with sdk target 13?

Tags: android, admob

I would like to know if phones with Android 2.3 or lower could download Apps with:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"  android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

and Build Target 15?

Becuase I have to do so to use the AdMob jar.

Thanks

Comment: They can, but it's up to you to test on downlevel devices and make sure "Class/method not found" errors don't pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, any device running SDK version 7 and above will be able to install your application. The `targetSdkVersion` attribute doesn't restrict devices from installing your application. Instead, it specifies the maximum API level on which your application should be able to run on.

Just be careful that you protect earlier versions of Android from making use of the new methods provided in SDK 15, as this will cause your application to crash.

Comment: Use Lint (http://tools.android.com/tips/lint). It checks for code where your app accesses APIs used in a later API level than your minimum.

Comment: "it specifies the maximum API level on which your application can run" - this is incorrect, and blatantly contradicts your previous sentence.

Comment: @Sam_D, you're right... sorry for being so blatant haha, it was a typo. I changed "can run" to "should be able to run on". Is that more clear?

Answer (score 2):

Yes they can, this is the goal of the `android:minSdkVersion` attribute. It prevents users with an older android version to download and install the app.